# NMinimize - Strange "function value is not a number" error

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

I am seeing strange behaviour in some code I have written that uses NMaxmimize. Here is a minimal working example:

```
f[a_] := Max[Flatten[{If[a >= 0, {0, 1}, 0]}]]
f[0.934340750282022`]
With[{a = 0.934340750282022`}, f[a]]
Max[Flatten[{{0, 1}}]]
NMinimize[f[a], a]
```

For me (Version 12.2.2.0 on MS Windows 64 bit) this gives output:

```
1
1
1
NMinimize::nnum: The function value {0,1} is not a number at {a} = {0.934341}.
```

So despite the function f being successfully evaluated to a number outside of NMinimize, in NMinimize it apparently produces a non-number. From the error it seems to be related to the use of Flatten, it seems the list {{0,1}} is not flattened to {0,1} when Flatten is used in NMinimize. But outside of NMinimize it is working correctly. Does anyone have any ideas of what might be going on?

Edit:
Working code based on J. M.'s ennui suggestion:

```
Clear[f]
f[a_?NumericQ] := Max[Flatten[{If[a >= 0, {0, 1}, 0]}]]
f[0.934340750282022`]
With[{a = 0.934340750282022`}, f[a]]
Max[Flatten[{{0, 1}}]]
NMinimize[f[a], a]
```

Comment: May I suggest using `NumericQ[]` in your function definition? See e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037).

Comment: Great, that solves, it, thank you! But why does it work with NumericQ and not without? I couldn't understand it despite reading the page you linked.

Comment: Does this explain it?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037

Comment: I can't quite understand it. I understand the explanation of https://support.wolfram.com/12502, but there the examples involve a numerical function inside the function that one needs to use NumericQ to define. I can't see anything numerical about the operations in the definition of the function f[a] above.

Comment: Revert to your original def. of `f[]` and execute `f[a]`.  That is the expression `NMinimize` will optimize.  It evaluates to `{0, 1}` whenever `a >= 0`, and `{0, 1}` is not a number, but a list.  Repeat with the `?NumericQ` check. (I will be notified of a reply if you use @MichaelE2 in your comment.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah, I see, it treats the list as a list with one symbolic expression which flatten doesn't do anything to, and then max of a list with one symbolic expression is apparently just the symbolic expression. Makes sense, thanks a lot!

Comment: Right. I will add that learning what evaluates (like `Max`), what doesn't, and how to control it with things like `?NumericQ`, `Evaluate`, and `HoldAll`, was one of the more confusing learning curves of Mathematica. BTW, a 2+ argument `Max` won't have the evaluation problem: For instance, `f[a_] := Max[0, If[a >= 0, 1, {}]]`.